# 誰かの胸の夜の空に伝えたい気持ちが生まれたら meaning

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, reading-comprehension

This line is from [流れ星の正体 of Bump of Chicken](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a000673/l04ca42.html):

> 誰かの胸の夜の空に伝えたい気持ちが生まれたら

Which meaning is suitable?

1. When you have a feeling that you want to tell someone’s night sky in his heart.
2. When you have a feeling that you want to tell something to someone’s night sky in his heart.
3. When someone has a feeling that he wants to tell (in his night sky in his heart).
4. When someone has a feeling that he wants to tell something (in his night sky in his heart).

Comment: Can you give us your best choice and why you think that is the case?

Comment: Do you have more context? None of those make sense. What is 胸の夜の空? Is this some kind of poetry?

Comment: This is a part of 流れ星の正体 of Bump Of Chicken

Comment: Is this like some sort of riddle you want us to solve, or is this a question you have?

Comment: Lyrics of Japanese pop songs are very often like this; it's almost a riddle without reading the entire lyrics. At least grammatically speaking, option 2 is a possible interpretation, too. You can choose the right option with confidence only after understanding the whole context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read it as AにBが産まれたら ("when B is born/produced in/at A") where A is 誰かの胸の夜の空 ("night sky within someone's heart") and B is 伝えたい気持ち ("passion/feeling to tell something (to someone)"). に is a static location marker (i.e., where something exists) rather than a destination marker here. So 4 is the closest among the four options.

This interpretation aligns with what's written in the next line:

> 伝えたい誰かの空へ向かう
>   It (=伝えたい気持ち) will head to the sky of someone he wants to tell (the message) to

So 誰かの胸の夜の空 in the first line is clearly a starting point rather than a destination. This is why option 2 is wrong even though it may seem grammatically possible. Imagine something like telepathy is happening, and 流れ星 is the invisible message itself (or its "carrier").

Comment: You don’t think both 誰か in 誰かの胸の夜の空に and 誰か in 伝えたい誰かの空へ向かう mean the same person, right? It’s not what I imagined first. Thank you for your good opinion.

Comment: @Yamacure They're different two people. 伝えたい誰か in isolation is indeed ambiguous ("someone who wants to tell the message" vs "someone who he wants to tell the message to"), but people usually don't use 誰か twice to refer to the same person. And the song is clearly about "messages" exchanged between 君 and 僕.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. 3 or 4 will be the best.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question.

Since it's a poem no one can really deny any of your choices, but the most natural thing to think is that the words are personifying the *night sky* in someone's heart.

So, the translation would be *When/If the night sky in someone's heart gets a feeling to tell something*.

I believe you can understand that the "night sky" is actually the "someone" himself.